# Task Scheduling Laravel on Cpanel not running

Tags: laravel, task, scheduling

i try to create a post every 1 minute. But it is not running. please check for me i wrong my code. thank you

PostCommand.php

```
    protected $signature = 'post:create';
 
    protected $description = 'Create new post';

    
    public function handle()
    {
        DB::table('xs5p')->insert([
            'matrathuong' => 'Nguyen Thi ha',
            'ghichu' => 'Day la noi dung bai viet',
            'g0' => 1
        ]);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\PostCommand'
    ];

    
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('post:create')->everyMinute();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa8Fe.jpg)

Comment: 1. Make sure that the path of artisan file is correct - 2. Check log file for possible errors - 3. Try to use `Log::info('working')` instead of inserting data and then check log again. 4. Try to do sth else with pure PHP and cron job and make sure that cron job is OK with pure PHP. 5. activate email for cron job and check your email. 6. Contact hosting support and ask them to answer this stack overflow question :)

Comment: is that on shared or dedicated hosting?